# Is there way to secure insecure connection?

Tags: security, connection, protected

Sometime we visit sites, but they don't have protected connection, is it possible to add some external layer of encryption (may be watch one site through the other)?
Couple month ago I saw a function called Anonymous View by Startpage.com search engine when you could watch the other site and via Startpage (the site's page would have a blue frame around it), actually it made to not allow where you watching from, but it seems they removed it.

Comment: Not really. The problem is the server on the other side. Let’s say you somehow use a proxy like what you describe on StartPage; the data still needs to get to the destination server and if there is no encryption there there is no way past that: Data will be transmitted to them in an unencrypted way.

Comment: I disagree with the above commentor, you can always add an extra level of protection by using an encrypted network, by using a proxy, even if the original connection is insecure, the transmission between you and your proxy would be secure... I strongly recommend using tor, maybe this sounds like advertisement but they don't pay me, I recommend it because it's free and genuinely good...

Comment: @XeнεiΞэnвϵς Yes, steps can be taken to mitigate risks. But the thing with websites that don’t use HTTPS is they will be targeted by hackers for system compromise. The hops in between? Not so much. Knowing that having a rock solid secure connection between you and the destination is one thing. But the final destination — a weak server  — will be the most likely place a hack will take place. Why monitor one individual user’s network path when to hack things when the destination will naturally be weak and inherently a destination for many?

Comment: hi, see if it's helpful to you: https://www.welivesecurity.com/2020/10/05/5-steps-secure-connected-devices/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot *completely* secure the connection between you and your destination if the target destination doesn't support the security you want, but you can reduce risk by using a vpn service:

- **Pro:** Encrypts the connection between you and the VPN host.
- **Pro:** The VPN service can be hosted anywhere in the world, making it seem (to your destination) that you are located elsewhere.
- **Con:** Most VPN services are paid, it costs money to host things
- **Con:** The VPN service can read all the traffic you send through it
- **Con:** The final connection between the VPN host and the destination is still insecure.

A vpn service my be a good way to tell Netflix you're in a different region, but is not perfect for some other use cases.